# Is there a way to add case that will add only some data to Record if it find something

Tags: erlang

I have a program that check content of program status with expected status. While defining **Record123** that will be used later in program I would like to check if **ProgramState** returns **premium** and if yes then add **'PremiumValue' = true** to record otherwise do nothing.

```
#'Record123'{
    'SomeRecordData1'
    'SomeRecordData2'
    .
    .
    .
    case lib_proc:(ProgramState) of
        premium ->
            'PremiumValue' = true;
        _ ->
            %%do nothing
    end,
}
```

Only way I could make it work is to assign result of case to 'PremiumValue' but it won't work when lib_proc/1 returns something else than premium. It will then fail checking for reveived record with expected.

```
#'Record123'{
    'SomeRecordData1'
    'SomeRecordData2'
    .
    .
    .
    'PremiumValue' = case lib_proc:(ProgramState) of
        premium ->
             true
    end,
}
```

I wonder if it is possible to do nothing in case it receives something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Erlang, every field in a record always has a value.  If you don't specify a value, it defaults to `undefined`.  So you could specify the default value explicitly:

```
#'Record123'{
    'SomeRecordData1'
    'SomeRecordData2'
    .
    .
    .
    'PremiumValue' = case lib_proc(ProgramState) of
        premium ->
            true;
        _ ->
            undefined
    end,
}
```

You can also do it in a later step:

```
MyRecord1 = #'Record123'{
    'SomeRecordData1' = apple,
    'SomeRecordData2' = orange
},
MyRecord2 =
    case lib_proc(ProgramState) of
        premium ->
            %% update the PremiumValue field 
            MyRecord1#'Record123'{'PremiumValue' = true};
        _ ->
            %% leave the record unchanged
            MyRecord1
    end,
```

Note that because of Erlang's single assignment feature, you're strictly speaking creating a copy with the updated field and storing it in the variable `MyRecord2`.  The original record is still accessible in the variable `MyRecord1`, so make sure you're using the right variable name later on.

Comment: Would it be ok to do as following:
create record 
#'Record123'{
    'SomeRecordData1',
    'SomeRecordData2'
}
then check 
case lib_proc(ProgramState) of
        premium ->
            %%Add value to already defined record
        _ ->
            %%do nothing
    end,

Answer (score 1):

You can set default values in record definition, in this case probably false. 
You can also do it this way to avoid setting a new value alltogether:

```
 Rec = case lib_proc(ProgramState) of 
   premium -> #'Record123'{... 'PremiumValue' = true ...}; 
   _Else -> #'Record123'{...}
 end.
```